# Guidelines to convert DH parameters to URDF specifications?

Tags: ros, kinematics, urdf, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do some of you have experience in creating URDF models from DH parameters of your robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85921/guidelines-to-convert-dh-parameters-to-urdf-specifications?/) by [mbkv](https://answers.ros.org/users/605/mbkv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DH parameters are a method to deal with the most simple parameters for a robot description. So the conversion from DH to URDF are quite easy.

I did the work on the other way around, from URDF to DH.

Do not hesitate to detail any specific concern.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) with karma: 107 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-01**:
How did you do the conversion of URDF to DH? I know OpenRAVE can do this automatically, but any other way would be good to know, too.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-10-02**:
Manually. My robot was the youBot, which is basically a RRR arm. The DH parameters are easy to find for this kind robot, it's the angle between the links and the length of the links.

You probably expect something more powerful. Why do you want to use DH?